# Show / Hide nested div jquery html

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

Ok so I'm trying to build a nav using a unordered list that shows a div when on li hover. I'm working within the wordpress loop so this is my HTML:

```
<div class="menu-header-container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'menu',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 10,
                    'offset' => 0,
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
            <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <div class="overlay">
            <p><?php the_field('sub_menu_item_one'); ?></p>
        </div>
```

This parts *seems* to be working fine. This is my jquery:

```
<script>
    $(".menu-header-container li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".overlay").stop().fadeIn();
    },function(){
        $(this).find(".overlay").stop().fadeOut();
    });   
</script>
```

This is my CSS

```
.menu-header-container {
    overflow: visible;
    float: right;
    width: 74%;
    margin-top: 4%;
}
.menu-header-container li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}
.menu-header-container ul li a {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 5%;
    font-size: 1.3125em;
    font-family:'MuseoSans300';
    text-transform: capitalize;
    display: block;
}
.overlay {
    display:none;
}
li > .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 25%;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

And here's my output:

```
<div class="menu-header-container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Knowledge Center</a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#">Client Services</a>    
            <div class="overlay">
                <p>Technology For You</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

So when I hover over one of the line items it shows everything in all the nested divs, I think its a jquery issue I'm having but it may be wordpress.

Comment: I heard you're supposed to use `jQuery` instead of `$` because of conflict errors, try that.

Comment: Your li items should close after each link ends. Since that isn't happening, all the links are contained in a single li item

Comment: @downvoter: why would you downvote this question, Sire ?

Comment: I imagine you were downvoted (*not by me*) because the question was really easy to resolve...you should always follow proper tabbing this issue would of been avoided if you had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML corrected:

```
<div class="menu-header-container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'menu',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 10,
                    'offset' => 0,
                    'order' => 'ASC'
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
            <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
            <a href="#"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <div class="overlay">
                <p><?php the_field('sub_menu_item_one'); ?></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man, I was expecting to be something much more complicated that I just took for granted my html ok. Thanks again! @AdityaSaxena

Comment: @editor: thanks to you, I don't know how tabbing works in SO to indent code